# MSSQL sort and concatenate data be state

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Is it possible to sort data like my example?

I want to concatenate `start/stop` or `start/error` state into one row.
I tried pivot table, but still don't know how to define it to make it work. Becasue one order can have more errors, or labors, but complete order ends with `stop`

```
    ID  LaborID     OrderNr           StateID   State   OrderStatusDate
102610  15784158    OPT2201652              1   start   28.01.2022 08:18
102625  15784158    OPT2201652              0   stop    28.01.2022 09:15
102630  15784158    OPT2201655              1   start   28.01.2022 09:31
102632  15784158    OPT2201655              0   stop    28.01.2022 09:43
101519  10134088    OPT2134651              1   start   11.01.2022 14:42
101524  10134088    OPT2134651              2   error   11.01.2022 15:27
101612  10134088    OPT2134651              1   start   13.01.2022 09:30
101642  10134088    OPT2134651              2   error   13.01.2022 15:01
101783  10134088    OPT2134651              1   start   17.01.2022 12:44
101800  10134088    OPT2134651              0   stop    17.01.2022 14:19
101646  10134088    OPT2134787              1   start   14.01.2022 07:56
101661  10134088    OPT2134787              0   stop    14.01.2022 09:03
```

To this:

```
LaborID     OrderNr        start               stop               error              minutes
15784158    OPT2201652     28.01.2022 08:18    28.01.2022 09:15                      0:57
15784158    OPT2201655     28.01.2022 09:31    28.01.2022 09:43                      0:12
10134088    OPT2134651     11.01.2022 14:42                       11.01.2022 15:27   0:45
10134088    OPT2134651     13.01.2022 09:30                       13.01.2022 15:01   5:31
10134088    OPT2134651     17.01.2022 12:44    17.01.2022 14:19                      1:35
10134088    OPT2134787     14.01.2022 07:56    14.01.2022 09:03                      1:07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to self-join, you can do this **in one scan** using window functions

```sql
WITH NextValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      NextState = LEAD(State)           OVER (PARTITION BY LaborID ORDER BY OrderStatusDate),
      NextDate  = LEAD(OrderStatusDate) OVER (PARTITION BY LaborID ORDER BY OrderStatusDate)
    FROM YourTable t
)
SELECT
  LaborID,
  OrderNr,
  start = OrderStatusDate,
  stop  = CASE WHEN NextState = 'stop'  THEN NextDate END,
  error = CASE WHEN NextState = 'error' THEN NextDate END,
  minutes = DATEDIFF(minute, OrderStatusDate, NextDate)
FROM NextValues t
WHERE State = 'start';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=258c73a31d2677ca03562c57d302dff6)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with some CASE or subqueries...

Here is the version with subqueries

```
SELECT DISTINCT LaborID, OrderNr,
       (SELECT OrderStatusDate FROM T AS Tin WHERE Tin.LaborID = Tout.Labor_ID AND Tin.OrderNr = Tout.OrderNr AND StateID = 1) AS start,
       (SELECT OrderStatusDate FROM T AS Tin WHERE Tin.LaborID = Tout.Labor_ID AND Tin.OrderNr = Tout.OrderNr AND StateID = 0) AS stop,
       (SELECT OrderStatusDate FROM T AS Tin WHERE Tin.LaborID = Tout.Labor_ID AND Tin.OrderNr = Tout.OrderNr AND StateID = 2) AS error
FROM   T AS Tout
```